# Fatal error out of memory in joomla

Tags: memory, joomla, php, fatal-error

I'm using joomla. 
I have php.ini file in the root. It contains this code

```
memory_limit = 96M
```

I created a phpinfo file and viewed the configuration. I see memory_limit 96 there which is correct.

But i have a different file in a subdirectory.

libraries/joomla/environment/browser.php

It shows `Out of memory (allocated 7864320)` error.  I created a phpinfo file in that folder but when i view the file it actually using this settings.

```
/usr/local/lib/php.ini
```

I see the memory limit as `200M` but still browser.php file throwing fatal error. Can anyone tell me whats wrong and why that file using different php.ini file

Comment: Which version of Joomla do you use ?

Comment: well it might be possible, that for several reasons your php.ini might not be loaded. Please put "phpinfo();" in your joomlas index.php and look, which php.ini is loaded..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 1.5.11? Do you have some suicidal tendencies? 
UPGRADE!

Answer (score 1):

On line 117 of

```
libraries/joomla/error/exception.php
```

change from

```
$this->backtrace = debug_backtrace();
```

to

```
$this->backtrace = debug_print_backtrace();
```